# Request password when running a shell script

Tags: shell, request, passwords

I have written a script and I want to put a password on that script, when the user executes the script, he will be asked for that password (the password that I set) and if the password is correct, the rest of the code will be read, But if the password is wrong, Close script
(License)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: On top of @GrumpyCrouton question. this isn't very practical because anyone with a text editor can read a shell script.